# What is the difference between Fixnum and Numeric

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, numeric, fixnum

They seem equivalent, but when comparing them, it's false:

```
5.is_a? Fixnum
# => true
5.is_a? Numeric
# => true
Numeric == Fixnum
# => false
```

Comment: `Numeric` is the base class for all numbers classes like `Fixnum`, `Float` or `Rational`. Search for _ruby numeric class hierarchy_ to get an overview.

Comment: ah, thanks! Looking it over, would you agree to the following:
everything that is a Fixnum is an instance of the class Numeric, but not everything that is a Numeric is a Fixnum

Comment: @GMarx exactly, it's `Fixnum < Integer < Numeric < Object`. You could also conclude that *"every Integer is an Object, but not every Object is an Integer"* - quite obvious, isn't it?

Comment: Perfect, thank you @Stefan

Answer (score 7):

**NUMERIC**

Numeric is the class from which all higher-level numeric classes should inherit.

Numeric allows instantiation of heap-allocated objects. Other core numeric classes such as Integer are implemented as immediates, which means that each Integer is a single immutable object which is always passed by value.

**FIXNUM**

Fixnum holds Integer values that can be represented in a native machine word (minus 1 bit). If any operation on a Fixnum exceeds this range, the value is automatically converted to a Bignum.

Fixnum objects have immediate value. This means that when they are assigned or passed as parameters, the actual object is passed, rather than a reference to that object.

**NOTE:** Every Fixnum is Numeric but but every Numeric is not a Fixnum.

**UPDATE:** Ruby 2.4 unifies fixnum and bignum into integer.

Answer (score 3):

`Numeric == Fixnum` returns `false` because they're different classes.

`is_a?` doesn't check the specific class an object is, that would be `instance_of?`. This is the documentation for `is_a?`:

> Returns true if class is the class of obj, or if class is one of the superclasses of obj or modules included in obj.

As mentioned in the other answer, `Fixnum` is a subclass of `Numeric`, this is why `5.is_a? Fixnum` and `5.is_a? Numeric` both return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

`is_a?` is not the same as `instance_of?`, it is the same as `kind_of?`. So your first two lines do not show that `Fixnum` and `Numeric` are the same. The third line shows that they are different. In fact, `Fixnum` is a subclass of `Numeric`.